# Sum last two records including last record of a group

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2017, how do I sum the last two records and show the last record in a single query?

```
CREATE TABLE Billing
(
    Customer CHAR(12),
    Month INT,
    Amount INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO Billing VALUES ('AAAA', 3, 5)
INSERT INTO Billing VALUES ('AAAA', 2, 0)
INSERT INTO Billing VALUES ('AAAA', 1, 2)
INSERT INTO Billing VALUES ('BBBB', 10, 0)
INSERT INTO Billing VALUES ('BBBB', 12, 1)
INSERT INTO Billing VALUES ('BBBB', 11, 0)
INSERT INTO Billing VALUES ('BBBB', 13, 6)
```

Expected output:

```
Customer   Total Last 2 Bills   Last Bill
-----------------------------------------
AAAA                         5          5  
BBBB                         7          6
```

I tried using `SUM` with `LAST_VALUE` with `ORDER BY`

Comment: Your question and your sample data are not quite consistent.

Comment: Hrm the last two monts in AAA are 3, 2 with values of 5 and 0... the last two months of BBBB are 13 and 12 with values of 6 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out rows by using the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function, as in:

```
select
  customer,
  sum(amount) as total_last_2_bills,
  sum(case when rn = 1 then amount else 0 end) as last_bill
from (
  select
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by customer order by month desc) as rn
  from billing
) x
where rn <= 2
group by customer
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/299e1/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select customer, (prev_amount + amount), amount
from (select b.*,
             lag(amount) over (partition by customer order by month) as prev_amount,
             lead(month) over (partition by customer order by month) as next_month
      from billing b
     ) b
where next_month is null;
```

If you want to ignore values of `0`, then filter:

```
select customer, (coalesce(prev_amount, 0) + amount), amount
from (select b.*,
             lag(amount) over (partition by customer order by month) as prev_amount,
             lead(month) over (partition by customer order by month) as next_month
      from billing b
      where amount <> 0
     ) b
where next_month is null;
```

Comment: Darnit. I made it to simple.  What if I wanted last 12 months?

Comment: @ScottBoston . . . This answers the question that you asked.  You should really ask a new question as a *new* question rather than in a comment.